# Create a list of divisible integers in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and I'm trying to create an expression, that gives a list of integers from 0 to n, which are divisible by 3. The script I wrote doesn't work and I'm not sure for what reason.

```
zeroto :: Int -> [Int]
zeroto n = [x | x <- [0..n]]
           where
             x "mod" 3 == 0
```

Comment: You can add a filter by using a comma, like `[x | x <- [0..n], mod x 3 == 0]`, but here you can write it like `[0, 3 .. n]`.

Answer (score 7):

`where` doesn't work like that. It's not a filter -- it's locally-scoped definitions.

However, a list comprehension does *allow* for filters, you've just not put it in the right place.

```
zeroto :: Int -> [Int]
zeroto n = [x | x <- [0..n], x `mod` 3 == 0]
```

Alternatively, you could define a filter function in the where block and filter afterwards, but this is kind of silly.

```
zeroto :: Int -> [Int]
zeroto n = divisibleByThree [0..n]
  where divisibleByThree = filter (\x -> x `mod` 3 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way but using simple recursion it can be done as

`mod3Arr :: Int -> [Int]
 mod3Arr 0 = [0]

 mod3Arr n | n`mod`3 == 0 = smallerArr ++ [n]
           | otherwise = smallerArr
           where smallerArr = mod3Arr ( n - 1)`